# XSLT - Can I create a temp document that functions as a repository of document nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

Assume I have the following temp documents:

```
<xsl:variable name="emc">
    <people>
        <person id="1">
            <name>Jim</name>
        </person>
        <person id="2">
            <name>Joe</name>
        </person>
    </people>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="ibm">
    <people>
        <person id="1">
            <name>Joan</name>
        </person>
        <person id="2">
            <name>Allison</name>
        </person>
    </people>
</xsl:variable>
```

And I want to have another document to store the root nodes of the previous documents:

```
<xsl:variable name="store">
    <store>
        <doc>{$emc goes here}</doc>
        <doc>{$ibm does here}</doc>
    </store>
</xsl:variable>
```

I can do this, but I can no longer use the contents of a doc element as I could the values of $emc or $ibm.

That as,

```
<xsl:variable name="doc1" select="$store/store/doc[1]">
```

And have $doc1/people/person[1] be the same node as $ibm/people/person[1]

Is this possible in some version of XSLT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you need to store a set of document nodes is not a document, but a node-set. So instead of this:

```
<xsl:variable name="store">
    <store>
        <doc>{$emc goes here}</doc>
        <doc>{$ibm does here}</doc>
    </store>
</xsl:variable>
```

just do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="store" select="$emc | $ibm"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0 this is strictly a node-set, so you have no control over the ordering. In XSLT 2.0 you can define a node-sequence, by using the "," operator in place of "|", and the nodes will then be in the order required.

Comment: So, I just want to make sure that I CAN'T store it somehow in a document? That's ultimately what I want to do. I need the structure provided by the document. If I pass around the "store" via template parameters I have a lot of management to do and it's hard to get around the stack nature of template calling. Thanks.

Comment: @Fred, a document node cannot have a parent. (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#DocumentNode) "Document Nodes can never appear as children" Therefore you cannot store a document within a document. If I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to effectively "wrap" (or atomize) the node to allow this to happen, but I guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `node-set` function which is specific for XSLT engines. For example, MSXML has `node-set()` function which converts tree to node-set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256197.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that in XSLT 1.0, the value of your literal XML stuff inside the variable instruction is a '[result tree fragment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments)' (RTF), which unfortunately cannot be processed directly as a node-set (except to treat it just as a single node with a string value). Therefore, XPath expressions using `/` or `[]` won't work on it.

The solution is either to use an [extension function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/) like `node-set()`, as @polishchuk said (but making it portable becomes trickier); or to use XSLT 2.0.

In XSLT 2.0, the [RTF data type is eliminated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#major-features) (and there was great rejoicing!). The value of a variable is a temporary tree, which can be operated on by XPath operators just like the source tree.

**Update:** preserving node identity

When you say "in the store document" (comment below), you mean in the temporary tree that is the value of the `$store` variable? As you have things structured in your question, it would be impossible because then some XML nodes must have two parents. But you could make the `$store` tree the actual location of the data, and have `$emc` and `$ibm` be selections from there:

```
<xsl:variable name="store">
    <store>
        <doc id="emc">
            <people>
                <person id="1">
                    <name>Jim</name>
                </person>...
            </people>
        </doc>
        <doc id="ibm">
            <people>
                <person id="1">
                    <name>Joan</name>
                </person>...
            </people>
        </doc>
    </store>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="emc" select="$store/store/doc[@id='emc']" />
<xsl:variable name="ibm" select="$store/store/doc[@id='ibm']" />
```

Then it will be true that `$doc1/people/person[1]` is the same node as `$ibm/people/person[1]`.

One can imagine some variations using `doc()` and external files, but before spending time on that I'd want to know more about your requirements, specifically, how the above scenario would not meet them.

Comment: I think you missed the comment that said that $doc1/people/person[1] and $ibm/people/person[1] must be the SAME node - (I think this is the IS relation in xpath). I want to be able to "store" the document nodes in the store document and extract them exactly as they were before being put in.<br> Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fred: you're right, I missed that comment, or else misinterpreted it. I'm not sure what you mean by being able to "extract them exactly as they were before being put in" that requires node identity as opposed to a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not really what I was looking for. In reality the closest thing would be a function that mapped the value of generate-id to a node(). Maybe in xpath 4.0 :)

Comment: @Fred, sorry it didn't meet the need. I'd be interested to know what the requirements are. Regarding the function you described, would a key with `use="generate-id()"` work? Not sure about getting the right document for it...

Comment: I use a key with generate-id, but I also have to pass around a sequence of document-nodes. I store the generate-id of both the element of interest and it's document node. I use the sequence to resolve the id. Kind of confusing, but it works. Thanks again.